# How to attach a html file within project directory and send it as mail?

Tags: python, django, attachment, email-attachments, coverage.py

I am trying to send the coverage report generated after execution of test cases, which is generated in htmlcov folder,

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from utils import email_utils


def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    to = ['xyz123@gmail.com']
    body = 'test'
    subject = 'coverage test'
    attachment = 'htmlcov/index.html'
    coverage_html = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR + '/' + attachment)
    email_utils.send_email_with_attachment(to, body, subject, coverage_html,
                                          'application/html',
                                          'index.html')
```

while doing so I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR | 2020-03-12 10:07:57,180 | MainThread | email_utils.send_email_with_attachment.69 | a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 342, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sgbackend/mail.py", line 66, in send_messages
    mail = self._build_sg_mail(email)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sgbackend/mail.py", line 125, in _build_sg_mail
    base64_attachment = base64.b64encode(attachment[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/base64.py", line 59, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s)[:-1]
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I checked if the file exists in the path, using if statement and yes it exists, is this something related to the way I am handling the files here? What should be the right approach?

this is the email sending I am functionality using:

```
def send_email_with_attachment(to_email, body, subject, attachment_content=None, main_type=None, file_name=None):
    data = {'from_email': settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, 'to': to_email,
            'subject': subject, 'body': body}

    logger.info("sending email")
    email = EmailMessage(**data)
    email.content_subtype = "html"

    if attachment_content:
        email.attach(file_name, attachment_content, main_type)
    try:
        email.send()
        logger.info("Email sent")
    except BaseException as e:
        logger.exception(e)
```

Comment: share your `send_email_with_attachment` code

Comment: @BakhtiyarBekbergen I have added the email sending functionality

Answer (score 0):

Hi Junior put your html file in templates folder and write below code and make sure in settings.py file you wrote Templates settings.

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from utils import email_utils


def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    to = ['xyz123@gmail.com']
    body = 'test'
    subject = 'coverage test'
    attachment = "index.html"
    coverage_html = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR + '/' + attachment)
    email_utils.send_email_with_attachment(to, body, subject, coverage_html,
                                           'application/html',
                                           "index.html")
```

Comment: @BakhtiyarBekbergen Please check attachment line inside the pytest_sessionfinish function